# GPS optimization, is really necessary?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gps, optimization

Some android users are experiencing GPS problems; are applications like this really useful and safe for all devices?

http://www.appbrain.com/app/gps-optimisation/com.gps.opt

What do you recommend for a 2.2 device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would depend on the device. Some devices have/had some real serious issues with their GPS. The Galaxy S is one of them. It can take 10 seconds for it to get a GPS lock or it could take a minute (or even more).

If you never have any issues with your device, then I wouldn't recommend running an application like this. If you can get a GPS lock within a few seconds or so and it is accurate, then I would say just leave it alone.

Comment: This may be due to their cellular network. GPS is jump-started by the cellular network - the rough location and time provided helps the chip determine which satellites are likely in view. If someone is testing on a device with only wifi it would easily take +3 minutes to get a GPS connection

Comment: I've had other android devices, on this network (T-Mobile), that had 0 issues with getting a GPS Lock. Samsung has said publicly that there are/were issues with the GPS chip/software on the Galaxy S devices. They have release an app that is supposed to correct it, but it never helped me, which is why I run a non-Samsung ROM, my GPS works "better" now...

Answer (score 3):

No idea what that app does.

If your GPS isn't locking as fast as you like, one option is to redownload the GPS assistance data. An app like "GPS Status" can do this for you. Here's a QR code for it.

[image: http://qqrr.it/mkt?pub:EclipSim]